# How to render custom html form using active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have following code to render custom form but it failed to load, any thing wrong i'm doing ?

```
collection_action :upload_csv do
    render "admin/csv/upload_csv"
end
```

my view is located at admin/csv/upload_csv.html.haml

**Any help is highly appreciated..**

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render` accepts a path relative to the `app/views` folder. Your view should be located at `app/views/admin/csv/upload_csv.html.haml` to be rendered as written.